# Apparent contradiction in the Rosh Hashanah menu/diet

Tags: halacha, minhag, food, rosh-hashanah-new-year, meal-seudah

On the one hand, on Rosh Hashanah we don’t eat sour/bitter foods, on the other hand we eat foods that have a negative connotation (see Orach Chaim 583:1) and apply them to our enemies - so why can’t we just eat something bitter with the intention of applying the bitterness to our enemies as well?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.34a.4 (I assume the reverse is kal v'chomer)

Comment: We have a pleasant minhag to eat sweet foods with appropriate invocations. You want that we should now eat bitter foods to ask for the bitterness to go on our enemies. Please don't suggest bitter minhogim. But if you could get the enemies to eat the bitter foods then ....

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a contradiction here at all but two different mesorahs. First you have the mechaber listing specific foods for rosh Hashanah then the Rema saying what the minhag Ashkenaz is which is honey in apple, pomegranate, and sweet foods in general